# Align Grid column to right

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, grid

I have a Windows Phone / XAML Grid composed by 3 columns. In particular, I want the third column to be aligned to the very right side of the screen.

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Marker" Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Name" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0" />
    <Image Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Selected" Width="48" Height="48"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
 </Grid>
```

The result, instead, is this:

[image]

When it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there no `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` ?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is this Grid a part of `ItemTemplate` of `ListBox` because i can't see other items in Grid.

Comment: Yes, it's a user control created to customize each item on a ListBox

Comment: Set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` on `ListBoxItem`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you mentioned its an `ItemTemplate` of ListBox, what you can do is set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this :

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image x:Name="Selected" Width="48" Height="48"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Image Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Selected" Width="48" Height="48"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in Grid.

Comment: Using a ListView instead of a ListBox may make life earier for multi column lists.

Comment: This is standard stuff. Look up a tutorial on ListViews, e.g. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFListView.aspx gives you a nice example. I always use ListView or DataGrid for tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it was fixed after removing the stackpanel